# Why can't I print an vector's begin() iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, stdvector, cout

So, i am just learning vectors and i have 2 questions.
First question:

```
std::vector<int> c{1,2,3};
std::cout << c.begin();
```

I know that i should put a `*` before `c.begin()` to output the 1 ,but why does `std::cout` give me an error if i don't put the pointer sign? Shouldn't it simply output the address of the first element of c? The error is "no match for operator <<".

Comment: One question at a time please. About the second question though - don't think about optimization. Nobody said this code is supposed to be efficient.

Comment: An iterator is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> know that i should put '*' before c.begin() to output 1 ,but why does cout give me an error if i don't put the pointer sign?

Because the compiler doesn't know how to "print" a value of `c.begin()`'s type. But let's just read [the error](https://godbolt.org/z/W8bEfj) (GodBolt; using GCC), which is very important to do:

```
<source>:10:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream'
(aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator' 
(aka '__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >'))
    std::cout << c.begin();
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
```

in other words:

> I don't know how to apply the `<<` binary operator when on the left-hand side you have a `basic_ostream<char>` and on the right-hand side you have a "normal iterator" corresponding to an std::vector

So, even though the iterator for `std::vector<int>` might have been a simple `int*` - that's not necessarily the case: It can be some class struct with a pointer member, or a pointer to the beginning of the vector and an integer offset etc. The language standard does not (AFAICR) guarantee this implementation detail.

Comment: @HeroForFun: It actually isn't, see edit. And anyway - unless the language standard guarantees it to be - yo can't make assumptions about that either.

Comment: i would have another question about vectors , can you help me?I don't want to post another question

Comment: @HeroForFun: Why is it confusing to you? That is, why were you expecting the iterator to be `int *`?

Comment: When i create the vector, some contiguos adresses are alocatted for it,which will store integers. When i do auto i = v.begin(),i think i is just a pointer that points to the start of an int array... What other type can it have?

Comment: @HeroForFun: Well, for example, it could be a struct with a pointer member. It could have a pointer to the beginning of the vector, and an integer offset value. Those are perfectly usable. Since you're new to the language, you can't afford to say "Oh, but surely the implementation cannot be anything other than XYZ". If it's not guaranteed, than don't make assumptions about it. (And even when you're more experienced it's better to avoid these assumption).

Comment: @HeroForFun: On StackOverflow, instead of thanking people, you upvote their answer. And if the answer is acceptable, your can accept it by pressing the "v" icon near the top of the question, below the score.